# How to manage AWS rotated keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, hashicorp-vault, amazon-kms

I need to talk to AWS API Gateway and  I want to access AWS APIs from external application. currently, my plan is to store the gateway credentials in Hashicorp Vault. But API gateway credentials are rotated periodically. So I need to keep adding credentials in my vault whever api gateway creds are rotated. What is an efficient way to store and manage rotated creds? Would you suggest any key management service that can talk to KMS to get the latest creds?

Comment: What keys? You can't get any private keys from KMS.

Comment: Api gateway and my AWS cross-account credentials are rotated periodically. What is an efficient way to store such rotated credentials? I don't want to have the burden of manually updating the creds in my vault every time the API creds are changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try Parameter Store or Secrets Manager. Those are the only services that are provided by AWS for key management.